# How to integrate Script tag into a body tag at end in an SPFX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

Hi I'm trying the java script example in my SPFX web-part. Below is my JavaScript you can refer.
[JavaScript Code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAPAM6F2IGS2)In the page click on the "Yammer" to get he dailog box

This is using Helmet. But didn't find any success.

[Helmet Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-helmet-loading-script-jh9ye)

```
 public onInit(): Promise<void> {    

//SPComponentLoader.loadScript('//s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js');


const script1 = document.createElement("script");
script1.src = "https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"
script1.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
script1.type="text/javascript"
document.body.appendChild(script1);

const script = document.createElement("script");
const scriptText = document.createTextNode("var options = {customButton : true, classSelector: 'mybutton-css-class',defaultMessage: 'My custom Message',pageUrl: 'www.microsoft.com'}; yam.platform.yammerShare(options);");
script.appendChild(scriptText);
script.type="text/javascript"
script.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

In render I'm Providing the tag like this,

```
public render(): void {
 var html = '<div><span class="mybutton-css-class">Yammer</span></div>'
 this.domElement.innerHTML = html;    

 }
```

But I'm getting this following error,

**VM10224:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: yam is not defined
    at :1:140
    **
Any Suggestions  will be helpful.
Thanks

And I have followed most references to solve the issue but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2o4k9t7c/) working perfectly fine. I think you are not creating yam instance. That is why it is giving ReferenceError.

```
<html>
<body>

<span class="mybutton-css-class">yammer</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
    customButton : true, //false by default. Pass true if you are providing your own button to trigger the share popup
    classSelector: 'mybutton-css-class',//if customButton is true, you must pass the css class name of your button (so we can bind the click event for you)
    defaultMessage: 'My custom Message', //optionally pass a message to prepopulate your post
    pageUrl: 'www.microsoft.com' //current browser url is used by default. You can pass your own url if you want to generate the OG object from a different URL.
  }; 
  yam.platform.yammerShare(options);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**
After looking at your codesandbox link, what you can do is update your component like below

```
    function App() {
  //var options = { customButton:true ,classSelector: 'mybutton-css-class',defaultMessage: 'My custom Message',pageUrl: 'www.microsoft.com' };
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    const yam = window.yam;
    yam.platform.yammerShare({
      customButton: true,
      classSelector: "mybutton-css-class",
      defaultMessage: "My custom Message",
      pageUrl: "www.microsoft.com"
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet />
      <span className="mybutton-css-class" onClick={onClickHandler}>
        yammer
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And also you can include you script files in the **index.html** file in public folder before the **body** tag.

```
<body>
<noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      async="true"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      {`yam.platform.yammerShare({ customButton:true ,classSelector: 'mybutton-css-class',defaultMessage: 'My custom Message',pageUrl: 'www.microsoft.com' });`}
    </script></body>
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same in react , which is not working. In JS it is working.But not in the react.

Comment: Can you share you minimal example in React so that i can help?

Comment: Check this link <a href="https://codesandbox.io/s/react-helmet-loading-script-jh9ye?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark">
  <img alt="Edit React Helmet loading script" src="https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg">
</a>

Comment: Please check my updated answer, also i forked your sandbox. I hope it can be the accepted answer now.

Comment: In SPFX there is no index.html

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/yammer-example-03ltz check this link, it has popup running